# Is there a simple fix to rotate a css oval shadow on a path rather than a central anchor?

Tags: css, rotation, css-transforms

I have a rotating box shadow around an oval for a loading icon. In a perfect circle, this would be no problem, but since I would like to add a logo to it, I would rather it rotate around a path rather than an anchor in the middle.

Currently, I have the shape before rotation perfectly made, but upon adding the @keyframes rotation, it rotates around the anchor in the middle of the object.
If you delete the @keyframes, that's the shape I'd like the colors to rotate around.

```css
.gradient-spinner{
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 margin: -20px -22px;
 width: 48px;
 height:36px;
 transform: rotate(138deg);
 border:1px transparent #ffffff;
 border-radius: 50%;
 box-shadow: 0 0 0 0px transparent inset,
             0 -5px 20px 0px rgba(1,197,255,0.4) inset,
             0 0 20px 0px rgba(0,150,130,0.4) inset,
             0 5px 20px 0px rgba(162,58,236,0.4) inset,
             0 5px 20px 5px rgba(1,197,255,0.4),
             0 0 20px 5px rgba(0,150,130,0.4),
             0 -5px 20px 2px rgba(162,58,236,0.4);
             
             animation:gradient 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes gradient{
 0%{
  transform:rotate(0deg);
 }
 100%{
  transform:rotate(360deg);
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="gradient-spinner z-i-100">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered putting the circle in a container and flattening the outer container instead of the circle? An example is shown below:

```css
.gradient-spinner{
 
 width: 48px;
 height: 48px;
 transform: rotate(138deg);
 border:1px transparent #ffffff;
 border-radius: 50%;
 box-shadow: 0 0 0 0px transparent inset,
             0 -5px 20px 0px rgba(1,197,255,0.4) inset,
             0 0 20px 0px rgba(0,150,130,0.4) inset,
             0 5px 20px 0px rgba(162,58,236,0.4) inset,
             0 5px 20px 5px rgba(1,197,255,0.4),
             0 0 20px 5px rgba(0,150,130,0.4),
             0 -5px 20px 2px rgba(162,58,236,0.4);
             
             animation:gradient 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes gradient{
 0%{
  transform:rotate(0deg);
 }
 100%{
  transform:rotate(360deg);
 }
}

.flatten {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -20px -22px;
  transform: scaleY(0.75);
}
```

```html
<div class="flatten"> 
    <div class="gradient-spinner z-i-100">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ahh. Didn't occur to me to try nesting it and manipulating from there. Appreciate the response, I think that'll work perfectly.